# How do i stop only a specific app from opening my web browser without stopping all other apps from opening url's windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser, opera

I have a program that I use every day, but every time I open it, it opens a browser tab advertising a YouTube channel, would there be a way to stop this application from opening my browser (opera) OR to close opera whenever a tab with that specific URL is open with a macro, browser extension or something like that.

I have tried changing the name of the opera executable from opera.exe to 1opera.exe, and now the app doesn't open that pesky web page, but now, I can't open URL's from any app

And worst of all, all of the answers to other similar questions are either completely unrelated to my problem or just say that it's not possible.

I am completely lost here, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author, or is it a prirated copy ?

Answer (score 1):

Opera, like other browsers, has addons.  You can find them [Here](https://addons.opera.com)

The ones that are on top of the list to try are

1. Popup Blocker [Download Here](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/popup-blocker-ultimate/) It may be able to consider the launch as a popup.
2. Channel Blocker [Download Here](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/channel-blocker/) will "block anything you like".

And you can definitely block any URL with most Anti-Virus Applications.  I use Malware Bytes [Download Here](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)

Disclaimer, I am not associated with any of these addons or applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any permission you can easily set, but I can think of some workarounds. It is probably using the http protocol handler, but changing that will break other things.

You could create a new user and run the program as that user. Disable execute access to the web browser by that user.

Put the program in a container or VM.

Look for a setting in the program to turn off the youtube link or contact the developer.

An antivirus or personal firewall program may allow you block usage of protocol handlers.

Since the program seems a little suspect, I'd probably try running it in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

1. step 1: getbrowser tamer
2. step 2: get some browser you dont use (download one)
3. step 3: make it so that the app only opens that browser (the one you
   dont use)
4. step 4: delete the unused browser
5. step 5: ez